# Hosting your SharePoint Framework solution for on-premises deployment

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-framework

does anyone knows how to Host SharePoint Framework solution for on-premises deployment ?

i have created a new site for Apps Catalog under my web application in Central Administration, also i have created a webpart using SPFx and generated its .sppkg file and uploaded to the apps catalog but i didn't see my webpart in my on premises solution.

as per video tutorial, i need to upload webpart files and i want NOT to host them on azure but i want to host them on my SharePoint 2016 environment or may be on local  sharepoint Farm. how can i do that?

check out the [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2016-support) and go to the section named "Hosting your SharePoint Framework solution for on-premises deployment -> SharePoint 2016" i'm facing issues here

Comment: Did you find any solution about that ?

Answer (score 0):

dont want to sound stupid but have you made sure that your using the correct release version?

> Since SharePoint Online and SharePoint 2016 have different release
>   cycles for new capabilities, they also have different capabilities
>   when it comes to the SharePoint Framework. SharePoint Online always
>   uses the latest version of the SharePoint Framework, but SharePoint
>   2016 only supports the version which matches the server-side
>   dependencies of the deployed packages.+
>
> SharePoint 2016 Feature Pack 2 supports SharePoint Framework
>   client-side web parts hosted in classic SharePoint pages built using
>   the **SharePoint Framework v1.1.0**. This means that when you are
>   targeting the SharePoint 2016 platform, you'll need to use the
>   SharePoint Framework v1.1.0 due to the server-side version
>   dependencies.

also due to restrictions on 2016 and adding .jsom files

> SharePoint 2016 - You can also host your files in the local SharePoint
>   farm itself. You can, for example, define a standardized site in your
>   farm where all the SharePoint Framework assets are being hosted.
>   **Take note, however, that by default .json files are not allowed to be uploaded to SharePoint 2016 libraries. So farm level settings will
>   need to be adjusted for this option**.

to unrestrict the files (.jsom) then you need to update it in central admin under security -> Define blocked file types.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Types-of-files-that-cannot-be-added-to-a-list-or-library-30be234d-e551-4c2a-8de8-f8546ffbf5b3#ID0EAADAAA=2016

if all the above is correct then when you add the .sppkg file to the app catalog did you deploy it? once deployed it should be visible in the Apps page section under "apps you can add"

Comment: Yoman generator 1.3. understand  On-Premise and Cloud :) 

look here --> https://youtu.be/U61D0DyCIlA?t=34m16s

Comment: After bundle solution, upload in document library only js files, json files are not required!

Comment: Thanks for your reply man, i'm aware of SharePoint 2016 Feature Pack 2 and it is already installed, also i've already removed .json file from the blocked list from CA. i have also deployed the solution to apps for sharepoint catalog. my question is where to upload webpart files?

Comment: In Document library :) best practice is Site collection level --> Style Library

Comment: when you say "where to upload webpart files" what do you mean? i think you missed a step. good that you have done most of the required steps but now go to "site content" and click on "add an app" -> find your custom app (if deployed) and click on it to add it. once its added under "site content" (might take a little time) it should be visible when you want to add it to a page within "webpart"

Comment: @Ali webpart has been deployed but when i got to site contents->add an app and i cannot see my component, as per my understanding i need to upload js and json files in sharepoint somewhere. then i can see the stuff.

Comment: as per the video reference            
    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LGLMxnmHk6U&list=PLR9nK3mnD-OXZbEvTEPxzIOMGXj_aZKJG, he is uploading the webpart files to azure CDN but i want to upload files into my SharePoint 2016 or local sharepoint farm? so what files i need to upload in order to use the component

Comment: yes at 08:30 is the point that you need to refer to and follow from that point. Yes he points cdn to azure but you just point it to a document library that will host those js and jsom files. You then need to manually upload the files to the library that you point to.

Comment: @AliJafer i've followed all steps and guidelines as well i have set my sharepoint portal site url to host webpart files(2 js and 1 json file) to the style library and deployed the solution successfully but there is no app available when i go to site contents->add an app......i have 1 webapplication and placed files under this URL http://serverName:2020/Style Library/HelloThere....and i didn't get my app so i placed webpart files under the apps catalog site url http://serverName:2020/sites/AppCatalog/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Style%20Library/Helo but no good luck

Comment: Did this resolve the issue ?